# Editext lost focus inside a ListView when click on it in android app

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, focus

I have multiple EditText controls in Listview control. I have set numeric keyboard to all EditText in ListView. But when I click on any EditText, first numeric keyboard shows, and just normal (alphabetic) keyboard replace the numeric and EditText loses its focus. I have to click again on EditText to show numeric keyboard. How can I rectify this problem. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

```
Please try this one.. Put the input type of edit text is either number or phone
```

like this

```
     <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Tel"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `descendantFocusablity="beforeDescendants"` in your listiview tag as

```
<ListView
   ....
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    />
```

And also add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in manifest file under activity tag as

```
<activity
        android:name="yourlistviewactivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
         >
    </activity>
```

And add

```
listview.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

after initializing listview in your activity.

Comment: Hello Giru Bhai, Thanks for answering. But it is not working for me. Actually I have Custom ListView class. And than I am using it as ListView control.

Answer (score 0):

In your EditText xml add "inputType='Number'"